# Changing the value of HTML input tag

Tags: vba

I want to change the value of an `input` tag in internet explorer with the help of VBA.

The markup for the element is as follows:

```
<input class = "sc-jTzLTM gyzInv" name = "linkInput0" placeholder = "Ex: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WW_aUQ" type = "text" data-icon = "youtube" id = "linkInput0" value = "" />
```

When I use the following code

```
ie.document.getElementById ("linkInput0").value = "sample"
```

Instead of changing the value, the value of the placeholder changes to "sample"

Comment: FWIW an `input` HTML tag has absolutely nothing to do with an `InputBox`

Comment: Does the value of the placeholder change, or is it just the CSS styling is not updated when you set the value via VBA? What do you get if you use `Debug.Print ie.document.getElementById ("linkInput0").value` immediately after setting the value?

Comment: @TimWilliams 

i write this code after setting the value 
MsgBox ie.document.getElementById("linkInput0").Value
And the sample was inside the msgbox

but in ie the value of element Still empty

Comment: Is there an url we can use please?

Comment: @QHarr 
https://www.aparat.com/uploadnew

Comment: Do you have access to using selenium basic for vba?